# Convex hull of a set is equivalent to the convex hull of the extreme point of the set?

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Assume $X$ is a compact set (not necessarily convex). If the following equality holds true?
$$\text{Conv}(X)=\text{Conv}(\text{extr(X)})$$
where $\text{extr}$ means the extreme point of $X$. The definition of the extreme point is that a point $a$ is said to be an extreme point of the set $X$ if the point $a$ cannot be represented as a convex combination of any other two distinct points in $X$.

Specifically, I am dealing with $X$ being a union of finite hyperrectangles ($X=\cup_{i=1}^{k}R_i$ where $R_i=\{r_{i,1},...,r_{i,m}:0\leq r_{i,j}\leq c_{i,j}\}$ for any $i\in\{1,...,k\}$ and $c_{i,j}$ may be different among indeces $i,j$) where each coordinate is non-negative.

I cannot find any counter-example that the equality is false.

**Edit**: I think that this equality is not true since one can easily construct three 2-D rectangles such that $\text{extr}(\text{Conv}(X))\subseteq\text{extr}(X)$, namely, $\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(\text{Conv}(X)))\subseteq\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(X))$. That is, we have $\text{Conv}(X)\subseteq\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(X))$.

Comment: In finite dimensions this is true.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your reply. The dimension is indeed finite. But could you provide me with some references to show that the equality is true? Thank you!

Comment: Corollary 18.5.1 of Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis". The infinite dimensional analogue is the Krein Milman theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat However, our compact set $X$ is not a convex set. I remember that the K-M theorem tells that if a set is compact convex, then the set is a convex hull of its extreme points.  So, apply K-H to my problem, I get $$\text{Conv}(X)=\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(\text{Conv}(X)))$$ But I am not sure whether $$\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(\text{Conv}(X)))=\text{Conv}(\text{extr}(X))$$ or not.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that it was an exact equivalent, just a direction if you decided to investigate higher dimensions. The reference is for finite dimensions.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your reply. I only want to investigate the finite dimension case as I said "The dimension is indeed finite". I am just not sure why you say that "In finite dimensions this is true." in your first comment. Therefore, I left my second comment.

Comment: It is not true in general in infinite dimensions.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your reply. But I cannot understand that why this is true in finite dimension.

Comment: @jerry Krein-Milman does not assume the set is convex, only compact in a Hausdorff, locally convex TVS. What is important, in infinite-dimensions only, is that you take the closed convex hull, not just the convex hull. A helpful result to this end: the closed convex hull of a compact set is also compact (in finite-dimensions, remove the word "closed"). So, any new extreme points created by $\operatorname{\overline{conv}} X$ will still be in the closed convex hull of $X$, and the more general version of Krein-Milman follows. (Warning: my knowledge really only extends to Banach spaces here.)